# Getting error: argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`

Tags: rust

I have the following:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::*;

fn main() {
    let mut struct_a: struct_A = struct_A::new();
    loop {
        let _res = struct_a.process();
    }
}

pub struct struct_A<'a> {
    pub entities: struct_B<'a>,
}

impl<'a> struct_A<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> struct_A<'a> {
        let mut struct_A: struct_A = struct_A {
            entities: struct_B::new(),
        };

        struct_A
    }

    pub fn process(&mut self) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.entities.get_connection(832);
        Ok(())
    }
}

pub struct struct_B<'a> {
    chain: Chain<u32, struct_c<'a>>,
}

pub struct struct_c<'a> {
    // other fields here
    u: &'a u32,
}

impl<'a> struct_B<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let cache = HashMap::new();
        struct_B {
            chain: Chain::<u32, struct_c>::new(cache),
        }
    }

    pub fn get_connection(&self, mac: u32) -> Option<&'a mut Node<struct_c>> {
        self.chain.find(mac)
    }
}

pub struct Chain<K, V> {
    pub cache: HashMap<K, *mut Node<V>>,
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Node<T> {
    pub data: T,
}

impl<K, V> Chain<K, V>
where
    K: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash,
{
    pub fn new(pool: HashMap<K, *mut Node<V>>) -> Self {
        Chain { cache: pool }
    }

    pub fn find(&self, key: K) -> Option<&mut Node<V>> {
        if let Some(node) = self.cache.get(&key) {
            unsafe {
                return Some(node.as_mut().unwrap());
            }
        }
        None
    }
}
```

and compile, I get:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `struct_a` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:7:20
  |
```

When I compile, I get:

```
  --> src/main.rs:25:9
   |
15 | impl<'a> struct_A<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
24 |     pub fn process(&mut self) -> Result<(), String> {
   |                    - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
25 |         self.entities.get_connection(832);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
```

If I add lifetimes to `process()` like:

```
  pub fn process<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Result<(), String>
    where
        'b: 'a,
    {
        self.entities.get_connection(832);
        Ok(())
    }
```

and compile, I get:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `struct_a` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:7:20
  |
7 |         let _res = struct_a.process();
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                    |
  |                    `struct_a` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
  |                    first borrow used here, in later iteration of loop
```

I'm really struggling to understand why I'm getting the original compilation error to begin with, I think it has got something to do with `variance` but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: The lifetime annotations on `get_connection()` are incorrect.

Comment: What about " `struct_a` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop first borrow used here, in later iteration of loop" is unclear?  You wrote a structure against the rules.  For example you could try to rewrite `process` so that it is non mutable or create a unique `struct_a` for each iteration

Comment: I still don't understand why `get_connection` returns a mutable reference to a Node for `'a`. You never even use the return value...

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_connection` returns mutable references to nodes in the list that live for `'a`, which in this case is basically the entire lifetime of the list. This also forces the `&self` reference of `get_connection` to be borrowed for at least `'a`.

Now in `process` you're taking a reference to `self.entities` and calling `get_connection`. Because of the above, this reference has to be borrowed for at least `'a`. Thus the entire `&mut self` reference in `process` must live for at least `'a`. This is the first error you're getting, since it's not guaranteed.

You adding a `&'b mut self where 'b: 'a` constraint "solves" this issue, since `process` now borrows for sufficiently long. But it's still incorrect.

In your main you have `struct_a` living for at least as long as the loop. So the `'a` parameter here corresponds to this actual lifetime in the code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut struct_a: struct_A = struct_A::new(); // 'a starts here
    loop {
        let _res = struct_a.process();            // 'a continues, struct_a has to live here
    }
                                                  // struct_a no longer used, lifetime ends

}
```

So `struct_A::new` creates a `struct_B` instance that has to live at least as long as the containing `struct_a`, setting `'a` to `struct_a`'s lifetime. Then, each call to `process` must borrow for *at least* `'a`, mutably. Therefore each iteration of the loop must borrow `struct_a` mutably for its entire lifetime, which is impossible since only one mutable reference can exist at a time.

From the code you provided there's no reason for `process` to take a mutable reference, since it doesn't mutate anything. If you instead make that reference `&'b self where 'b: 'a`, everything works and compiles. The references are still taken for the entire duration of the loop, but since they're immutable they can coexist.

See [in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d8d2d59a118807c8676c5dcf4972de2e).

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, but this is a scaled down version of the problem I made for stack overflow, in the actual design, I will need to mutate `struct_a`, how can this be done given my original code?

Comment: We're getting into X/Y territory now. It depends on what kind of mutation you want to perform. You should incorporate that into the code you posted, we cannot really help without knowing the intent behind the `mut`s here.